# For without Next error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to programming, and VBA, and seem to be a bit stuck with a piece of code I have written. I understand that I need to put in a next inbetween the two Fors on my code, I'm just not sure where and what should follow.

Please help!! Here's my code if anyone can help me!

```
Sub Order()
    rowdata = 1
    Do While Cells(rowdata, 1) <> ""
        rowdata = rowdata + 1
    Loop    
    dataend = rowdata - 1
    rowwrite = rowdata + 2
    Cells(rowwrite, 1) = "Item Code"
    For col = 1 To 3
        Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(1, col)
    Next col
    rowwrite = rowwrite + 1

    target = Cells(2, 7)
    **For** rowdata = 2 To dataend
        If Cells(rowdata, 1) = target Then
            Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 5) - 1
        End If
        If Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 4) Then
            **For** col = 1 To 3
                Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(rowdata, col)
            Next col
            rowwrite = rowwrite + 1
        End If

End sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: notice : `**For** rowdata = 2 To dataend`

Comment: Your true answer is indenting that means to deep inner codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
**For** rowdata = 2 To dataend
    If Cells(rowdata, 1) = target Then
        Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 5) - 1
    End If
    If Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 4) Then
        **For** col = 1 To 3
            Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(rowdata, col)
        Next col
        rowwrite = rowwrite + 1
    End If
Next rowData
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your indents to a more standard method.  There are two places you can put your "Next" statement it just depends on the logic you need.  I've put in in between loops but if you can nest the loops (one inside the other) if that is what you need logically.

```
Sub Order()
    rowdata = 1
    Do While Cells(rowdata, 1) <> ""
        rowdata = rowdata + 1
    Loop
    dataend = rowdata - 1
    rowwrite = rowdata + 2
    Cells(rowwrite, 1) = "Item Code"
    For col = 1 To 3
        Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(1, col)
    Next col
    rowwrite = rowwrite + 1

    target = Cells(2, 7)
    For rowdata = 2 To dataend 'your ** line
        If Cells(rowdata, 1) = target Then
            Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 5) - 1
        End If
    Next 'new Next

    If Cells(rowdata, 5) = Cells(rowdata, 4) Then
        For col = 1 To 3
            Cells(rowwrite, col) = Cells(rowdata, col)
        Next col
        rowwrite = rowwrite + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks both, its fixed the code. However, its not quite doing what I expected it to unfortunately. Will have a fiddle around with it and hope for a miracle!

Comment: So the macro is now working (thank you!) However, where the target is "cells(2,7)"I need it to work down column G (i.e. col 7) until it reaches the end of the data, its only 6 rows. Am I missing something really simple to be able to do this?! Any help would be much appreciated once more!

Comment: @Antler19 There are lots of ways to do what you want but it's a little unclear what some of your variables are.  Do you want to check all the cells in the range G2:G7?